# Printing only the decimals value

Tags: c#, .net

For instance:

```
decimal test = 5.021m;
```

I would like to print 4 decimals after the decimal point (so in this case, 0210). My only solution I could think of is

```
decimal test = 50.021m;
test.ToString("0.0000").Split('.')[1].Dump();
```

which does print 0210... but seems incredibly silly to me. Is there a better format I can use to do this?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure its silly. I think my first solution would have been more complicated than that, this seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: To be on the safe side, make sure you specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` so the decimal separator is always a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest an extension method (or static method, if you prefer) for the fraction. Unfortunately a generic version is tricky, though it can be done instead:

```
public static decimal Fraction(this decimal d) => d - Math.Truncate(d);

public static TNum Fraction<TNum>(this TNum d) => d - Math.Truncate((dynamic)d);
```

Then you can just format the fraction:

```
decimal test = 50.021m;
test.Fraction().ToString(".0000").Substring(1).Dump();
```

Another alternative is to use the modulus operator:

```
(test % 1).ToString(".0000").Substring(1).Dump();
```

Update: I added a `Substring` to skip the decimal separator, assuming it is one character.

Instead of math, you can do string processing, but rather than the overhead of `Split`, just use `Substring` and `IndexOf`:

```
((Func<string, string>)((s) => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('.')+1)))(test.ToString(".0000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Dump();
```

As an extension method:

```
public static string Fractional4<TNum>(this TNum num) {
    var strNum = ((IFormattable)num).ToString(".0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return strNum.Substring(strNum.IndexOf('.')+1);
}
```

Which you can call with

```
test.Fractional4().Dump();
```

Comment: Still not a big fan of the suggestion, I wish you could do something like `string.Format("{:N4}", test);`, but this works. Thanks

Comment: Well, for decimal it will be exact, for float/double not so much, and the generic version apparently uses `Math.Truncate(decimal)` by default. I do think it is a shame `Math` doesn't include some versions of `modf` for C#'s floating types. I added an alternative I found using `%` (modulus).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Math:

```
decimal test = 50.021m;
decimal absTest = Math.Abs(test);
decimal floor = Math.Floor(absTest);                       // 50
decimal digits = Math.Floor((absTest - floor) * 10000);    // 210
string output = digits.ToString("0000")                    // if you need the leeding 0
```

---

**Explanation:**

At first you need to take the absolute value of your `test` value, since the [`Math.Floor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

After taking the floor of your value and subtracting it from the absolute `test` value, you will get a delta. Now you have to multiply the delta with `Math.Pow(10, NumberOfDigits])` and cut following decimal places with another `Math.Floor`.

---

As extension method:

```
public static decimal GetDecimalPlaces(this decimal value, int numberOfPlaces)
{
    decimal absoluteValue = Math.Abs(value);
    decimal floor = Math.Floor(absoluteValue);
    decimal delta = absoluteValue - floor;

    decimal decimalPlaces = Math.Floor(delta * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, numberOfPlaces));

    return decimalPlaces;
}
```

Usage:

```
decimal posTest = 50.0210m;
decimal negTest = -50.0210m;

// Output: 0210
Console.WriteLine( posTest.GetDecimalPlaces(4).ToString("0000") );

// Output 021
Console.WriteLine( negTest.GetDecimalPlaces(3).ToString("000") );
```

Comment: Isn't the output for the negative number incorrect if it is 0021? I think you just need to change the ToString on it to be just three 0's instead of four.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad: Thanks for pointing that out. You are right. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Can also edit the remaining part after dividing 1.0 by the display digit.

```
        decimal test = 5.021m;

        Debug.Print(string.Format("{0:0000}", test % 1.0m * 10000));
```

Comment: "Keep it simple, stupid!" This should be marked as answer. _To fit also for negative values you can just write `string.Format("{0:0000}", Math.Abs(test) % 1.0m * 10000)`._